# ul.menu color not changing

Tags: html, css, colors

I've tried several ways but I'm not getting the color changed, must missing something here!

I need to change the text color to all those lower links on footer, how can i do it?

**MY HTML**

```
<!-- Footer -->
 <footer id="footer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p class="copyright">&copy; MY SITE - 2017 All Rights Reserved.</p>
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="terms.html">Terms<span> of Use</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy<span> Policy</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Downloads<span></span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </footer>
```

**MY CSS:**

```
#footer {
        padding: 5em 0 3em 0 ;
        background-color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #footer > .inner {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: calc(100% - 4em);
            width: 60em;
        }

        #footer .copyright {
            color: #000;
            font-size: 0.8em;
        }

        #footer .menu {
            color: #000;
            font-size: 0.7em;
        }

    ul.menu {
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

            ul.menu li {
                padding: 0;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-left: 0.75em;
                padding-left: 0.75em;
                border-left: solid 1px;
                line-height: 1em;
            }

                ul.menu li:first-child {
                    margin-left: 0;
                    padding-left: 0;
                    border-left: 0;
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g3m6orpg/

Comment: just add this in your css :  ul.menu>li>a {
    color:red;
   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this way in css

```
 ul.menu li a {  
     color : green;
  }
```

Also updated the fiddle link check it https://jsfiddle.net/g3m6orpg/3/

Comment: If I have solved this issue can you mark it solved , thanks

Comment: Your SIMPLE solution Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#footer ul li a { color:#000;}
```